# MySQL - slow access to the table index or table data

Tags: mysql

I have MyISAM tables with a big number of rows - 10M to 500M. The tables are used to store time series data infrequently and I would like to optimize it for `SELECT`, which I am doing throung 2 indexes: the epoch and a classifier column (which contain a few thousand categories).

My issue is that the first `SELECT` I do for a particular category is quite long (10 to 50 sec) while the subsequent ones are really fast, even when using `SQL_NO_CACHE`. Such a query will typically return between 100,000 and 1M elements.

Profiling shows that MySQL spends a lot of time "Sending data". This would indicate that a lot of the time spent is done doing disk I/O. But I do not really understand where the bottleneck is:

1. Is the bottleneck in the BTREE read? The tree has only a few thousands nodes and then less than 1M points in the selected node. I cannot believe it would take 30 seconds to do that on a modern machine, even with old school hard drives.
2. Is it in reading the rows in the table? That is again less than a million rows with an average length of ~40bytes.
3. Something else I am not accounting for?

Here are the query results:

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(`Time`) FROM archive_1 WHERE Channel=63;
+---------------+
| COUNT(`Time`) |
+---------------+
|        450619 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (28.67 sec)

mysql> SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(`Time`) FROM archive_1 WHERE Channel=63;
+---------------+
| COUNT(`Time`) |
+---------------+
|        450619 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (2.20 sec)

mysql> SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(`Time`) FROM archive_1 WHERE Channel=63;
+---------------+
| COUNT(`Time`) |
+---------------+
|        450619 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.88 sec)

mysql> SHOW PROFILES;
+----------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration    | Query                                                                             |
+----------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        1 | 28.66720725 | SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(`Time`) FROM archive_1 WHERE Channel=63 |
|        2 |  2.19872350 | SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(`Time`) FROM archive_1 WHERE Channel=63 |
|        3 |  0.87811475 | SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(`Time`) FROM archive_1 WHERE Channel=63 |
+----------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;
+----------------------+-----------+
| Status               | Duration  |
+----------------------+-----------+
| starting             |  0.000113 |
| checking permissions |  0.000010 |
| Opening tables       |  0.000027 |
| System lock          |  0.000017 |
| init                 |  0.000030 |
| optimizing           |  0.000018 |
| statistics           |  0.055731 |
| preparing            |  0.000024 |
| executing            |  0.000008 |
| Sending data         | 28.611161 |
| end                  |  0.000019 |
| query end            |  0.000005 |
| closing tables       |  0.000014 |
| freeing items        |  0.000021 |
| logging slow query   |  0.000003 |
| logging slow query   |  0.000004 |
| cleaning up          |  0.000005 |
+----------------------+-----------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 2;
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000105 |
| checking permissions | 0.000011 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000036 |
| System lock          | 0.000015 |
| init                 | 0.000028 |
| optimizing           | 0.000019 |
| statistics           | 0.032255 |
| preparing            | 0.000024 |
| executing            | 0.000007 |
| Sending data         | 2.166140 |
| end                  | 0.000020 |
| query end            | 0.000004 |
| closing tables       | 0.000014 |
| freeing items        | 0.000025 |
| logging slow query   | 0.000003 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000018 |
+----------------------+----------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 3;
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000071 |
| checking permissions | 0.000009 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000018 |
| System lock          | 0.000012 |
| init                 | 0.000021 |
| optimizing           | 0.000014 |
| statistics           | 0.000059 |
| preparing            | 0.000020 |
| executing            | 0.000007 |
| Sending data         | 0.877795 |
| end                  | 0.000021 |
| query end            | 0.000004 |
| closing tables       | 0.000015 |
| freeing items        | 0.000029 |
| logging slow query   | 0.000015 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000006 |
+----------------------+----------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The particular table I am querying contains 107,407,213 rows with a data length of 4,237,427,600 bytes and an index length of 4,255,541,248 bytes. I optimized it yesterday and there where no added data since then.

If the query is I/O bound, I can always switch to a SSD and I also have the option to store the time index as an integer instead of a double. But so far I do not understand where my bottleneck is and I would like to avoid major changes before knowing more.

Comment: The first time you run the query nothing is in cache, second time there is data in cache and hence the query execution is fast.

Answer (score 2):

SQL_NO_CACHE means that mysql should not use the query cache.

The disk/buffer cache is still used, which is why the first query takes longer time, and the subseqent queries are faster.

Comment: Thanks. Doing the math, I am retrieving ~20MB in ~30sec, leading to a read throughput of ~600KB/sec. Quite close to the 1MB/sec for a random read on a hard drive. I guess I will need to switch to a SSD if I want to improve the performances.

Comment: @EnguerranPetitfils If using InnoDB you can make a multi column index on (channel, time). That index will cover your entire query, not needing to read table data.

Comment: Unfortunately I recover more data than that, the query shown above is only for investigating things.But that is a really good idea